# How to filter Elasticsearch documents with multiple criteria on nested data?

Tags: elasticsearch, nested-fields

In ElasticSearch, I have nested data structured:

```
{"number":1234, "predictions": [ 
 {"variant":"blue", "startDate": "2023-02-22"}, 
 {"variant":"red", "startDate": "2023-03-01"}
]},  
...
```

The prediction field indicates which variants are available starting from specific dates.
I want to have a query that get the product that meets the following criteria:

- check the prediction which has the start date right before the provided date.
- make sure the prediction’s variant matches the provided variant

I tried to use a nested query with range to obtain predictions from the last week (since we only get one prediction per week):

```
"query": { "bool": {  "must": [
      {"nested": {
         "path":"predictions",
         "query": { "bool": { "must": [
            {"range": {
              "predictions.startDate": {
               "lte": "2023-03-02", 
               "gte": "2023-02-23", 
             } }}, {
             "match": {"predictions.variant": "blue"}
} ] } } } } ] } }
```

But I want to modify the query to also retrieve the prediction with the most recent start date.
I want to filter out products where the most recent prediction does not include the variant I specify.
Expected input and result:

```
variant: "blue", startDate: 2023-28-02 => 1234 is in the result
variant: "blue", startDate: 2023-03-02 => 1234 is not in the result
variant: "red", startDate: 2023-04-20 => 1234 is in the result
```